# Database design - Should i use one to one relationship?

Tags: php, mysql

I am designing a database that stores products (storage, cpus, mobos, memory etc...) and information about the products 
(specification, retailers that sells the specific product, and price)

Should i use one to one relationship for part_number and products (mobo, memory etc...) tables? or should i store each part_number in it's own product table and link price and products tables together with part_number?

Er diagram

http://prntscr.com/b5ovuj

Tables

```
Cpu table

=========================================
Id |part_number_id | Specifications ....
=========================================
1  |          1    |
2  |          2    |
3  |          3    |
4  |          4    |
=========================================

Mobo table
=========================================
Id   |part_number_id| Specifications ....
=========================================
101  |      101     |
102  |      102     |
103  |      103     |
104  |      104     |
=========================================

Memory table
=========================================
Id   |part_number_id | Specifications ....
=========================================
201  |      501      |
202  |      502      |
203  |      503      |
204  |      504      |
=========================================



Retailers
=========================================
Id |      name     |  Logo
=========================================
1  |     Pcparts   |  pcparts.png
2  |     bestpc    |  bestpc.png
3  |      LMNC     |  lmnc.png
4  |      GGWP     |  ggwp.png
=========================================


part_numbers 
=======================
Id |    part_number
=======================
1  |   BX80646I74790K
2  ||BX80646I54690K
3  |BX80648I75820K
4  |FD8350FRHKBOX
5  |FD6300WMHKBOX
6  |BX80646G3258
7  |BX80646I54590
8  |BX80646I34160
101|FD8320FRHKBOX
102|BX80646I54460
103|BX80648I75930K
201|BX80646I54690
202|FD9590FHHKWOF
203|AD740KYBJABOX
======================



Price
==============================================================================
Id | part_number_id |  retailer_id |         product_url           |  Price
==============================================================================
1  |        1       |       1      |http://www.example.com/prod/id |  122.33
2  |        1       |       2      |http://www.example.com/prod/id |  133.41
3  |        1       |       3      |http://www.example.com/prod/id |  110.00
4  |        1       |       4      |http://www.example.com/prod/id |  105.05
5  |       101      |       1      |http://www.example.com/prod/id |  122.33
6  |       201      |       2      |http://www.example.com/prod/id |  133.41
7  |       101      |       3      |http://www.example.com/prod/id |  110.00
8  |       101      |       4      |http://www.example.com/prod/id |  288,19
9  |       201      |       1      |http://www.example.com/prod/id |  244,19
10 |       204      |       2      |http://www.example.com/prod/id |  277.09
==============================================================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one table `part_numbers`, if you think and assume that part numbers will be `unique` in this table.  If part numbers are unique in this table then you are not reducing redundancy by introducing 3 more tables.

You can have one more `field/attribute` in `part_number` as `type` where you can can specify : CPU,Memory or Mobo.

Comment: Thank you helped alot :)

Answer (score 0):

In such case, I usually store common field in all type of products in one tables with name likes "Products" with common fields like  this:

```
ID,Title,Partnumber,...
```

and use the primary key in Products table as foreign key in other table like Mobo,Memory and etc